# Does MySQL Regexp support Unicode matching

Tags: mysql, regex, unicode, pattern-matching

Does anyone know if Mysql's regexp supports unicode?  I've been doing some research and the majority of blogs etc. seem to indicate that there is a problem or its not supported.  I'm wondering then is it best to use LIKE for unicode pattern matching and regexp for ASCII enhanced pattern matching?
I Like the idea of being able to search for matches at the beginning or end of a string, but if regexp doesn't support unicode then this could be difficult if my text is unicode.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. > Does anyone know if Mysql's regexp supports unicode? I've been doing some research and the majority of blogs etc. seem to indicate that there is a problem or its not supported.

   As documented under [Regular Expressions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/regexp.html):

   > #### Warning
   >
   > The [`REGEXP`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp) and [`RLIKE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp) operators work in byte-wise fashion, so they are not multi-byte safe and may produce unexpected results with multi-byte character sets. In addition, these operators compare characters by their byte values and accented characters may not compare as equal even if a given collation treats them as equal.
2. > I'm wondering then is it best to use LIKE for unicode pattern matching and regexp for ASCII enhanced pattern matching?

   Yes, that would be best.
3. > I Like the idea of being able to search for matches at the beginning or end of a string, but if regexp doesn't support unicode then this could be difficult if my text is unicode.

   One can do that with `LIKE` too:

   ```
   WHERE foo LIKE 'bar%'
   ```

   And:

   ```
   WHERE foo LIKE '%bar'
   ```

Answer (score 3):

[*MariaDB starting with 10.0.5*](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/pcre/) :

> REGEXP/RLIKE, and the new functions REGEXP_REPLACE(), REGEXP_INSTR() and REGEXP_SUBSTR(), now work correctly with all
>   multi-byte character sets supported by MariaDB, including East-Asian
>   character sets (big5, gb2313, gbk, eucjp, eucjpms, cp932, ujis,
>   euckr), and Unicode character sets (utf8, utf8mb4, ucs2, utf16,
>   utf16le, utf32). In earlier versions of MariaDB (and all MySQL
>   versions) REGEXP/RLIKE works correctly only with 8-bit character sets.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with Mysql 8.0, [unicode matching is supported](https://mysqlserverteam.com/new-regular-expression-functions-in-mysql-8-0/)

See also [the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#regexp-compatibility) for compatibility issues