# REGEXP with MySQL isn't working properly

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

If I want to search all data with the string `léon` in the `name` field, I use a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `my_table` WHERE `name` REGEXP 'léon'
```

This request is OK.

Now, I need to retrieve all rows with the string `léon` or `leon` or `lèon`, so I tried:

```
SELECT * FROM `my_table` WHERE `name` REGEXP 'l[éeè]on'
```

This query doesn't work... I have no error, but no result. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: It works for me... Maybe a version thing? What MySQL version are you running on?

Comment: if i try with SELECT * FROM `my_table` WHERE `name` REGEXP 'lé[o]n', it's ok. So it's not a problem with the version i think.

Comment: Doesn't appear to work in the fiddle - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/78eb95/3

Comment: I am running on MySql 5.5 and its running absolutely fine.

Comment: If you use a ISO-8859-x charset, it should work, if you use UTF-8 which is a multibyte charset, not so much.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson -- looks right: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0ffcb/1 -- post as answer!

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson: are you saying that regular expressions don't work with multi-byte character sets?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Unless something changed very recently, MySQL's REGEXP operator is not multi byte safe.

Answer (score 2):

MySQL's regexes [don't work reliably with multibyte character sets](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14356367/477878).

However, if you're using UTF-8, you can instead make use of the [accent insensitive `LIKE` and `=` searches](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/20bed/2) which looks like it may be what you're really after anyway.

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs:](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/regexp.html)

> The REGEXP and RLIKE operators work in byte-wise fashion, so they are
>   not multi-byte safe and may produce unexpected results with multi-byte
>   character sets. In addition, these operators compare characters by
>   their byte values and accented characters may not compare as equal
>   even if a given collation treats them as equal.

What you could try is handling the multibyte character like this so it is handling 1 byte or 2.  It won't be perfect because it will matchin on "lion" for example, but may get you closer.

```
REGEXP 'l.{1,2}on'
```

Another thing that might be affecting you is the way that REGEXP works in MySQL is that there are implied wildcards on the end because you are not specifying the the beginning and end so

```
REGEXP 'l[éeè]on'
```

is equivalent to

```
REGEXP '^.*l[éeè]on.*$'
```

This means that you might be matching MORE than what you expect.  Sounds like your problem is the first scenario I mention