# Searching by Unicode Range in MySQL

Tags: mysql, regex, unicode

Is it possible to search by Unicode range in MySQL? I have used this before, and I thought it worked:

```
SELECT * FROM people where surname NOT REGEXP "[\u0020\u0027\u002D\u0041-\uFF5A]"
```

The RegEx will find any surnames not composed of Latin characters, spaces, apostrohpes and hyphens, but it is not working on a table I am testing now.

From what I am reading, it seems this is not possible. If so, are there any workarounds? Such as specifying all the characters manually, e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM people where surname NOT REGEXP "[ -'abcdefg...]"
```

**UPDATE**: The above is an acceptable solution.

Comment: Why can't you just look for normal (non-inverted) regexp, like `[a-zA-Z '-]`?

Comment: Because that RegEx does not look for all the characters in the Latin Unicode tables.

Comment: I have no experience with MySQL, but try `"[\\u0020\\u0027\\u002D\\u0041-\\uFF5A]"`. The backslash character is the escape character in MySQL strings according to [MySQL String Literals](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/string-literals.html) documentation and must be therefore escaped with one more backslash.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It does not work though. It seems this is not supported by MySQL.

Answer (score 4):

An old-yet-important question that was answered by @Mofi's comment:

On MySql 8.0 and above, the Unicode prefix `\u` should be escaped: `\\u`.

So, for example, to search for the range a-z:

```
SELECT * FROM people where surname REGEXP "[\\u0061-\\u007a]"
```

On earlier versions, using Unicode is unsupported ([see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14356248/does-mysql-regexp-support-unicode-matching)), and what actually happens is a set match, e.g. for `[\\u0061]`, strings containing `u`, `0`, `6` or `1` are matched.

You can try it out with a fiddle that has both new & old version, [like this one](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/eiKBWPrNc6XmNVWW2MGkDY/0), and see for yourself.