# Mysql select fields in certain language

Tags: mysql

I have a column city that has values in two languages namely Greek or English, e.g. Athens or Αθήνα. How to make a query to get the row that has values only in English or only in Greek without any additional field about language ?

Answer (score 0):

Take only Greek:

```
SELECT * FROM `Mytable` WHERE HEX(city) REGEXP '^(..)*C[EF]'
```

Not Greek:

```
SELECT * FROM `Mytable` WHERE HEX(city) NOT REGEXP '^(..)*C[EF]'
```

There is no code for English. Some codes can be found in : 
[How to identify a language in utf-8 column in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37063793/how-to-identify-a-language-in-utf-8-column-in-mysql)