# Mysql 5.5 regexp brackets at the end of words

Tags: mysql, regex

I have a big issue with regexp in Mysql 5.5.
I have an expression:

```
edukacj[aąeęi] zdrowotnej
```

And the regexp engine finds only **edukacja zdrowotna**, but when I define the regexp like:

```
edukacj(a|ą|e|ę|i) zdrowotnej
```

it find correctly also **edukacji zdrowotna**.
Shouldn't the two above give th same result?

Comment: `zdrowotna` != `zdrowotnej` ... please include actual sample table data along with your current query or queries.

Comment: Might be a dupe of [Does MySQL Regexp support Unicode matching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14356248/does-mysql-regexp-support-unicode-matching)

Comment: This is the query i'm using: ```SELECT nazwa FROM `kursy` where nazwa regexp '[eę]duk[aą][cć]j[aąeęi] [zżź]dr[oó]w[oó]';```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that `REGEXP` was unable to handle UTF-8 characters "correctly" before MySQL 8.0.  With 8.0, collations are honored, and much of what you are doing can be simplified.

In particular, REGEXP simply looked at each *byte*, one at a time.  However, your accented letters require two bytes, thereby they are not handled correctly.

Here's an example of it working 'correctly' in 8.0:

```
mysql> SELECT "edukacją zdrowotna" regexp 'edukacj[aąeęi] zdrowotna';
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| "edukacją zdrowotna" regexp 'edukacj[aąeęi] zdrowotna'    |
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                         1 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
```

Or, to focus on the single *character*:

```
mysql> SELECT 'ą' REGEXP '[aąeęi]';
+-------------------------+
| 'ą' REGEXP '[aąeęi]'    |
+-------------------------+
|                       1 |   <--  1 == TRUE == it matched
+-------------------------+
```

I recommend you upgrade: 5.5 -> 5.6 -> 5.7 -> 8.0.  Or dump the data and reload on 8.0.  In either case, the upgrade will be quite time-consuming due to the large number of "little things" that have changed.

This chart shows that, with any collation (other than `utf8_bin`), `ą` = 'a':  http://mysql.rjweb.org/utf8_collations.html